# problema de regresion con git

Tags: git

¿Hola que tal tu ve un problema con git, me hizo un revert a una versión que no quería, así que tuve que reeditar todo el repositorio desde una versión aun más anterior
Actualmente el repositorio local no tiene ningún archivo GIT, como puedo agregar la carpeta local a un repositorio remoto, sin que se altere nada del local y reescriba todo lo que está en el remoto?

EJEMPLO
Tenía el repositorio X con la versión 56 y quería hacer un REVERSO DE CAMBIOS a la versión 55 pero en cambio lo que hizo fue un reverso a la versión 45
Desde el repositorio Baje la versión 55 y borre todos los archivos que hacen referencia a git me refiero a la carpeta ".git". Y trabaje sobre el repositorio hasta lograr las modificaciones que deseaba y quisiera colocarlo, no sé cómo agregar para que los cambios realizados se pueda subir al repositorio remoto como revisión 57, localmente no esta como repositorio pues la carpeta está totalmente borrada.
¿Como debo proceder? Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Llamemos carpeta `X` a la que tienes en local, la que no tiene repositorio (`.git`) y que tiene las cosas tal como las quieres tener.

Yo haría lo siguiente:

1. Clonar el repositorio remoto a otra carpeta temporal, llamémosla `Y`
2. Copiar (o mover) todo lo que hay en `Y/.git` a la carpeta `X`
3. Hacer un `git status` en la carpeta `X` para verificar que `git` detecta correctamente los cambios entre la versión 56 (que será la última disponible, por estar clonado del remoto), y el estado actual de la carpeta.
4. Si todo está bien, `git add`  de los cambios que te interesen y `git commit` con el mensaje adecuado. Eso creará la versión 57 en local.
5. `git push` desde la carpeta `X`. Eso subirá ese último commit al remoto.

Comment: El problema son los archivos que hay que borrar, cono realizó esa modificación, ese tipo de cambio es el que estaría evitando cierto?

Comment: Podrías por favor reformular la pregunta asi le pongo aceptada?

Comment: Ya esta ¡hecho!